# Clean a list of tuples from the permutations

Tags: python, list, permutation

I have a list of tuples that I generated thus:

```
frequencies = [(a, b, 40) for a in [x for x in range(20, 110, 10) if x != 90] for b in range(20, 90, 10)]\
+[(a, b, 40) for a in [x for x in range(20, 110, 10) if x != 90] for b in range(100, 175, 25)]\
+[(a, b, 40) for a in [x for x in range(20, 110, 10) if x != 90] for b in range(200, 400, 50)]
```

I would like to consider permutations s.a. (20, 60, 40) and (60, 20, 40) identical and so to keep only one of them.

My current approach is:

```
# Clean permutations
frequencies2 = list()
for f in frequencies:
    possible = list(itertools.permutations(f))
    if len([p for p in possible if p in frequencies2]) == 0:
        frequencies2.append(f)

frequencies = frequencies2
```

I am quite sure there is a better way to do this, but I can't find it.
Although this code isn't really aesthetic, it is only O(n²).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps a `if a != b` or even `if a < b` filter on the outer loop?

Comment: I removed it in the edit but just in general, note that 'else: continue' at the end of any loop is about as redundant a statement as can be

Comment: @VeltzerDoron It is redundant, but it helps for the code readability (When you get to 8 to 10 indents, with a lot of different scenarios tested with if / else statements). Thanks for the answers!

Comment: If you get to 8 to 10 indents with a lot of different if / else statements, it is time to refactor that code into more readable chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter out permutations after the generation is complete then you can simply sort the tuples and compare them:

```
without_permutations = list({tuple(sorted(f)): f for f in frequencies}.values())
```

This builds a dict in which the sorted tuples point to the original tuples. That way, later tuples will overwrite earlier permutations of themselves.